# How to get current user in forms.py def save(self)?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-users

How to get user logged in `def save(self, commit=True)` at `forms.py`. I tryed `self.request.user`, but doesn't work...`self` doesn't have `request` :/

Can anyone help me?

Comment: @MattheusSoares Hey man, if my answer solved your problem, I would be very glad if you could accept it kindly.

Answer (score 2):

Use `form_valid` function to assign user to a variable.

```
class PutYourClassNameHere(generic.CreateView):
    # your code here
    ...

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(PutYourClassNameHere, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the request to the form's save method. Try like this:

Override the `form_valid` method to pass request to form's **save** method:

```
class YourView(..):
     def form_valid(self, form):
         form.save(commit=True, request=request)
         return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

In your form:

```
def save(self, commit=True, request=None):
   instance = super(YourFormClass, self).save(commit=False)
   user = request.user
   # rest of your logic
   instance.save()
   return instance
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because request is not passed into your form's save() method. So basically you should override `get_form_kwargs` method of form in views and pass `request` object to it.

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kw = super(MyModelCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kw['request'] = self.request
    return kw
```

Comment: I’m using CBV generic.CreateView, how method I will to override in my view?

Comment: check this link `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/flattened-index/#CreateView` . generic.CreateView has a method called `get_form_kwargs()`, just override it and pass the sample code that i mentioned in the post to it.